# Genexus 17u5 Inteligencia Artificial - desde API SOAP

Tags: api, genexus, inteligencia-artificial

Estoy implementando una API Soap con Genexus 17u5 tomcat8 y compilado en jdk1.8, donde le paso un texto para traducir, el idioma de entrada y el de salida y me devuelve el texto traducido. Para esto utilizo el modulo de GenexusAI y el procedimiento "translate".

El tema es que si lo implemento en un WebPanel funciona correctamente, pero si utilizo el mismo código pero en un procedimiento el cual lo levanto como API Soap, me devuelve un error http 500.

Puede ser que que por WebPanel me funcione porque la sesión esta activa y por API no?
Desde ya gracias!

Adjunto error http 500:

<!doctype html>HTTP Status 500 â€“ Internal Server Errorbody {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}

## HTTP Status 500 â€“ Internal Server Error

**Type** Exception Report

**Message** com.genexus.servlet.ServletException: com.genexus.servlet.ServletException: com.genexus.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0

**Description** The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

**Exception**

```
com.genexus.servlet.ServletException: com.genexus.servlet.ServletException: com.genexus.servlet.ServletException: com.genexus.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
at com.vigo.aws_traducirtexto_impl.privateExecute(aws_traducirtexto_impl.java:370)
at com.vigo.aws_traducirtexto_impl.execute_int(aws_traducirtexto_impl.java:310)
at com.vigo.aws_traducirtexto_impl.webExecute(aws_traducirtexto_impl.java:267)
at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectBase.doExecute(GXWebObjectBase.java:220)
at com.vigo.aws_traducirtexto.doExecute(aws_traducirtexto.java:14)
at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callDoExecute(GXWebObjectStub.java:208)
at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callExecute(GXWebObjectStub.java:87)
at com.genexus.servlet.http.HttpServlet.doPost(HttpServlet.java:15)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.genexus.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:24)
at com.genexus.filters.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:32)
at com.genexus.servlet.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:14)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.genexus.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:15)
at com.genexus.filters.APIObjectFilter.doFilter(APIObjectFilter.java:38)
at com.genexus.servlet.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:14)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.genexus.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:32)
at com.genexus.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1231)
at com.genexus.servlet.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:14)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:882)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1647)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

```
com.genexus.servlet.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:20)
```

**Root Cause**

```
com.genexus.servlet.ServletException: com.genexus.servlet.ServletException: com.genexus.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
at com.vigo.aws_traducirtexto_impl.privateExecute(aws_traducirtexto_impl.java:370)
at com.vigo.aws_traducirtexto_impl.execute_int(aws_traducirtexto_impl.java:310)
at com.vigo.aws_traducirtexto_impl.webExecute(aws_traducirtexto_impl.java:267)
at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectBase.doExecute(GXWebObjectBase.java:220)
at com.vigo.aws_traducirtexto.doExecute(aws_traducirtexto.java:14)
at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callDoExecute(GXWebObjectStub.java:208)
at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callExecute(GXWebObjectStub.java:87)
at com.genexus.servlet.http.HttpServlet.doPost(HttpServlet.java:15)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.genexus.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:24)
at com.genexus.filters.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:32)
at com.genexus.servlet.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:14)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.genexus.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:15)
at com.genexus.filters.APIObjectFilter.doFilter(APIObjectFilter.java:38)
at com.genexus.servlet.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:14)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.genexus.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:32)
at com.genexus.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1231)
at com.genexus.servlet.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:14)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:882)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1647)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

```
com.genexus.servlet.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:20)
com.genexus.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:32)
com.genexus.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1231)
com.genexus.servlet.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:14)
```

**Root Cause**

com.genexus.servlet.ServletException: com.genexus.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
at com.vigo.aws_traducirtexto_impl.privateExecute(aws_traducirtexto_impl.java:370)
at com.v